Use a different template for duplicate automatic comments for reposted questions by the same user
It happens every now and then that a user reposts their question - maybe they don't know how to edit, maybe the question was closed and they wanted to dodge the review queue, or maybe they didn't get good answers the first time. This case is common enough that the duplicate closing system allows close votes even when the target question has no answers if they were posted by the same user. This exemption exists on all SE sites, unlike the extra special case of meta sites where the posts don't have to be by the same user.
Given this, the current automatic comment which recommends editing the current post shouldn't be posted for such cases. Especially when the target has already been closed, it encourages gaming the review system and reposting. Even when the target is still open, the comment should encourage editing the target and not the current post.
Now that we're posting increasingly longer recommendations in the autocomment, and since the check for this case already exists, I think the time has come for more custom recommendations depending on the situation. For discussion: Do you agree? Why or why not? If you agree, what do you think those custom recommendations should be?

Proposal for an automatic comment: "It appears you have already asked the same question at: [title and link to question] Please do not repost the same question again." or something like that.
